# Transfering from traditional GIS software developing to internet area

Tags: c++, server, career

I am a GIS developer, formerly doing some secondary development with GIS software. I now want to obtain some internet-based GIS area in my career.

Somebody advised me to first read some networking/linux books. When prepared, then transfer to some company to provide experience and so on.

Is there any opensource project belonging to this type: server side provide some service, for example, provide some navigation service(or other GIS area service).  I want to learn something about these software platforms and how to realize the functionality provided by server to client, Scheme about the whole thing. Ideall6 such type of thing is using in c++/c. Easier for me to learn.

My former area and expertise has been using desktop software.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a network-based project with a strong routing focus, written in C++, I can recommend Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM). It is (now) permissively licensed, and uses publicly available OpenStreetMap data.

You can find its home page at http://project-osrm.org/, although there is a lot of useful information in the [wiki](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki), which you should also check out.

There is a live example at http://map.project-osrm.org/

You can run it on Amazon EC2, however I'd recommend setting up a local linux box (Ubuntu, Debian or RHEL/Centos), even if you have to use a virtual machine instead of "real hardware".

Edits:
OSRM appears to be the most active of the C++ routing projects, but there are certainly others. [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/) is also an active project, in Java. For a list, see the [OSM web site](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

And there are many other good GIS projects. A search through [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/) (see list on right side) will give you some of the most popular. GeoServer and MapServer are well worth a try for servers. OpenLayers and [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) are popular on the web client side (for both maps and features). Open source GIS (even just those that are web-oriented) is a huge area - as I put in my comment for your question, you need to give us something more specific to work if we're to guess what might help you.